# Can I power Raspberry Pi 3 via 3V3 and GND pin?

Tags: power, pins, raspberrypi

Can I power my Pi 3 using the 3v3 pin (pin 1) and GND pin (pin 6)? Also, if I want to protect the board from power surges can I just put a fuse between my power supply and the 3v3 pin?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is not an Arduino question **BUT** definitely do **NOT** try this!

The Foundation [Hats Master](https://codeload.github.com/raspberrypi/hats/zip/master) has recommendations.

*"It is possible to power the Pi by supplying 5V through the GPIO (sic) header pins 2,4 and GND. The acceptable input voltage range is 5V ±5%. ⋯ Implement a duplicate power safety diode ⋯ supply 5V at a minimum of 1.3A ⋯ Under no circumstances should a power source be connected to the 3.3V pins."*

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry I posted it on the wrong stackexchange forum. I didn't know there even existed a raspberry forum.